# Load data into clickhouse from other clickhouse servers

Tags: etl, clickhouse

I need to load data into ClickHouse server from other ClickHouse servers.

I have four ClickHouse servers which have 25000 inserts/server/second approx. (100000 inserts/sec). I want to load data from all these database servers to a fifth server.

I have looked into table engines like URL or JDBC bridge but I was wondering what options do I have, for continuous push / pull or scheduled loads. Using files is not possible because of the large size and extra work. DBs are busy 24x7. What are the possible solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create tables with engine=Distributed on those 4 servers and point to it 5-th server, using `remote_servers` cluster description. And using Materialized View will intercept/duplicate inserts.

Answer (score 1):

@Denny Crane has answered to different question on github that's easier to understand.
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/15295#issuecomment-698960325
MaterializedView is an insert trigger.

> It gets data from INSERT.
>
> It never reads (selects) from table.
>
> You must create MaterializedView at a server where inserts happen. You
> can re-route MaterializedView output to remote server. create table
> xxx as remote(); create Materialized View .... to xxx as select .....

Use remote :
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/remote
Thanks again.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)